# Sitecore - Get Items by TemplateName in $props Parameters

Tags: powershell, sitecore

How to get the **items** with specific template only. I need this, beacuse it is useful for the **bucketable** items, like Tags

**Here is my code:**

```
$props = @{
    Title = "Test"
    Description = "Test"
    OkButtonName = "Run Report"
    CancelButtonName = "Cancel"
    Parameters = @(
        @{ Name = "TagName"; Title = "Tag Name"; Editor = "multilist"; Source = "/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/TagRepository/" }
        @{ Title = "Note"; Value = "SitecoreExchange"; Editor = "info" }
    )
}
```

**Here is the path (where I want specific template):**

```
Source = "/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/TagRepository/"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the  template query in your source like this : **/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/TagRepository/[@@templatename='TagTemplateName']**

and don’t forget to replace the **TagTemplateName** by the name of the template you want to filter.

**working code:**

```
 $props = @{
        Title = "Test"
        Description = "Test"
        OkButtonName = "Run Report"
        CancelButtonName = "Cancel"
        Parameters = @(
            @{ Name = "TagName"; Title = "Tag Name"; Editor = "multilist"; Source = "/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/TagRepository/[@@templatename='TagTemplateName']" }
            @{ Title = "Note"; Value = "SitecoreExchange"; Editor = "info" }
        )
    }
```